# neo4j fulltext search and exact value filter how do i write the query?

Tags: neo4j, full-text-search

Suppose i have some nodes, eg:nodeA, nodeB, nodeC and
nodeA follow nodeB
nodeA follow nodeC

each node has some properties like: id,nickname,age etc.

```
match (a:Node)-[f:follow]->(x:Node)
where a.id = 123 and x.nickname contains "jack"
return x
```

I had tried this method but the part "x.nickname contains jack"
is not fulltext search

And i know the fulltext search :

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("nodeByNickname", "jack") YIELD node
```

but how do i combine the two querys?

Two days later:
I have tryed the following way to query, but i have no idea if it is the right way for my situation, and it works

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("theIndexName","jack") yield node AS x 
match (a:Node) -[f:follow]->(x) 
where a.id = 123 
return x
```

Comment: The use of full-text indexes is a bit complex. You can start the learning process on [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/performance/index-configuration/introduction/), and following the links at the bottom to understand how to configure a full-text index and how to use such an index.

Comment: thanks a lot, i  had read the manunal, but i still can not found the way for my situation